# New Magento backend functionality

Tags: magento, collections, module, adminhtml

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/admin-part1-series-magento-admin-forms-grids-controllers-tabs).  The tutorial isn't 100% complete and leaves the user to fill in some of the gaps.  I'm fine with that.  The part that breaks is `$collection = Mage::getModel('employee/employee')->getCollection();`.  I'm assuming this is because I'm asking Magento to call a customer getCollection method which I need to define.  I've looked through and can't seem to find an example of how to create a collection file.

Can anyone point me to a few examples?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have `Employee` model defined?

Comment: Thank you WojtekT.  I was missing this piece from my etc/config.xml.  I'll update with my answer when SO allows me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you WojtekT.  I was missing this piece from my etc/config.xml

```
    <models>
        <categoryrules>
            <class>Rogue_CategoryRules_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>categoryrules_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </categoryrules>
        <categoryrules_mysql4>
            <class>Rogue_CategoryRules_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
                <rules>
                    <table>rogue_category_rules</table>
                </rules>
            </entities>
        </categoryrules_mysql4>
    </models>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1) file in **app\code\local\NCM\Employee\etc\config.xml**
<?xml version="1.0"?>

    <config>
    <modules>
        <NCM_Employee>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </NCM_Employee>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <employee>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>NCM_Employee</module>
                    <frontName>employee</frontName>
                </args>
            </employee>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <employee>
                    <file>employee.xml</file>
                </employee>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <employee>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>NCM_Employee</module>
                    <frontName>employee</frontName>
                </args>
            </employee>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <employee module="employee">
                <title>Employee</title>
                <sort_order>71</sort_order>               
                <children>
                    <items module="employee">
                        <title>Manage Items</title>
                        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        <action>employee/adminhtml_employee</action>
                    </items>
                </children>
            </employee>
        </menu>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <NCM_Employee>
                            <title>Employee Module</title>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                        </NCM_Employee>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <employee>
                    <file>employee.xml</file>
                </employee>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>   
    <global>
        <models>
            <employee>
                <class>NCM_Employee_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>employee_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </employee>
            <employee_mysql4>
                <class>NCM_Employee_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <employee>
                        <table>employee</table>
                    </employee>
                </entities>
            </employee_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <employee_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>NCM_Employee</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </employee_setup>
            <employee_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </employee_write>
            <employee_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </employee_read>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <employee>
                <class>NCM_Employee_Block</class>
            </employee>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <employee>
                <class>NCM_Employee_Helper</class>
            </employee>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>

2) file in **app\code\local\NCM\Employee\Model\Employee.php**

    class NCM_Employee_Model_Employee extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('employee/employee');
    }
}

3) file in **app\code\local\NCM\Employee\Model\Mysql4\Employee.php**

    class NCM_Employee_Model_Mysql4_Employee extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {    
        $this->_init('employee/employee', 'employee_id');
    }
}

4) file in **app\code\local\NCM\Employee\Model\Mysql4\Employee\Collection.php**

    class NCM_Employee_Model_Mysql4_Employee_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('employee/employee');
    }
}
```